# How can I instantiate the class DefaultHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to access the DefaultHashMap class but getting error in the main method. Could anyone please tell me what is the problem?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;


public class PythonToJava {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Random rm = new Random();

        int i = rm.nextInt(1000);

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> stats = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        DefaultHashMap<K,V> default = new DefaultHashMap<K,V>();

        System.out.println("Random Number Generated is: " + i);

                for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){

                    int value = rm.nextInt(500);

                    System.out.println("The value of VALUE is " + value);


                }


    }

}

class DefaultHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
      protected V defaultValue;
      public DefaultHashMap(V defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
      }
      @Override
      public V get(Object k) {
        V v = super.get(k);
        return ((v == null) && !this.containsKey(k)) ? this.defaultValue : v;
      }
    }
```

Please help me in rectifying the errors I'm encountering at the line with the code:

```
DefaultHashMap<K,V> default = new DefaultHashMap<K,V>();
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `K` and `V` are type parameters, and here, you need to use concrete types to substitute them, the same as when you are using `HashMap`.

Comment: Does this statement sounds good? `DefaultHashMap<value,0> defaultvalue = new DefaultHashMap<value,0>();`

Comment: The parameters are type parameters, so it should probably be <Integer, Integer> instead of <value, 0> (if value is of type int or Integer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the code as follows `class DefaultHashMap<Integer,Integer> extends HashMap<Integer,Integer> {
   protected Integer defaultValue;
   public DefaultHashMap(Integer defaultValue) {
     this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
   }
   @Override
   public Integer get(Object k) {
     Integer v = super.get(k);
     return ((v == null) && !this.containsKey(k)) ? this.defaultValue : v;
   }
 }` but still getting error at the first line which is `class DefaultHashMap<Integer,Integer> extends HashMap<Integer,Integer> {`

Comment: In this case, since the type parameters are not used, delete them will solve it. The class can be change from DefaultHashMap<Integer, Integer> to just DefaultHashMap. The link in the comment may be helpful too.

Answer (score -1):

K,V has to be objects
You cannot use variable default. Its a java reserve word.

You should read about java generics
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html